# Ray_cast cannot ignore external objects and related issues in LocalView?

Tags: scripting

## blender: 4.0.1

`Q1:` The results of the plug -in and the script editor are inconsistent

- mesh `a` in local view, `b` in global

Script editor:

```py
import bpy
visible_objs = bpy.context.visible_objects
print(visible_objs)               # out: [bpy.data.objects['a'], bpy.data.objects['b']]
```

Plugin:

```py
import bpy

bl_info = {
    "name": "demo",
    "category": "demo",
    "author": "",
    "blender": (3, 0, 0),
    "location": "",
    "description": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "version": ('0', '0', '1'),
}

def TEST_HT_btn(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        operator='demo.eg',
        icon='EVENT_A',
        text=''
    )


class DEMO_OT_Eg(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "demo.eg"  
    bl_label = ""        
    bl_description=""
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}    

    def execute(self, context):
        visible_objs = bpy.context.visible_objects
        print(visible_objs)           # out: [bpy.data.objects['a']]
        return {'FINISHED'}   


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(DEMO_OT_Eg)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus.append(TEST_HT_btn)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(DEMO_OT_Eg)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_editor_menus.remove(TEST_HT_btn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

## Why do the output results different?

---

`Q2:` Is the following code better?

```py
# Store the current view
view_distance = self.__rv3d.view_distance
view_matrix = self.__rv3d.view_matrix

bpy.ops.view3d.localview()        
all_visible_objs = context.visible_objects
bpy.ops.view3d.localview()

# Restore 
self.__rv3d.view_matrix = view_matrix
self.__rv3d.view_distance = view_distance
```

---

### The root cause of the above problems is that ray_cast cannot work properly under localView

ray_cast can only capture the square outside, even if it is not visible in LocalView, so I have to hide it

> This is just an example. There are actually many objects. I can only choose Scene.ray_cast

I have to get all the non -hidden objects other than LocalView, but this is not smooth, visible_get() always returns False.

Thanks！

[image]